# Create a list of values from nested dictionary Python

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

I have the following data structure:

```
listionary = [{'a': [{'id': 30, 'name': 'bob'}, {'id': 50, 'name':'mike'}]},
             {'b': [{'id': 99, 'name': 'guy'}, {'id': 77, 'name':'hal'}]}]
```

and I want to create a list of the values for each `'id'` key.

```
ie. lst = [30, 50, 99, 77]
```

I know I need three iterators to traverse through the structure:

one to access the two parents dictionaries inside the array, another to access the lists of keys `'a'` and `'b'`, and then a last to get the value of each `id` key in the nested child dictionaries

I tried

```
lst = [[x][y][y]['id'] for x, y, z in listionary]
```

but I got an error of

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)
```

Is there a clean way to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with 3 `for` loops in list comprehension:

```py
listionary = [
    {"a": [{"id": 30, "name": "bob"}, {"id": 50, "name": "mike"}]},
    {"b": [{"id": 99, "name": "guy"}, {"id": 77, "name": "hal"}]},
]

lst = [d["id"] for d in listionary for v in d.values() for d in v]
print(lst)
```

Prints:

```
[30, 50, 99, 77]
```

---

Explanation:

`for d in listionary` - this will iterate over all items inside list `listionary` (`{"a":...}, {"b":...}`)

`for v in d.values()` - this will iterate over all items inside these dictionaries (`[{"id:...}, {"id":...}], [...]`)

`for d in v` - this will get all dictionaries from these lists (`{"id:...}, {"id":...}, ....`)

`d["id"]` - this will get value from the key `"id"`

Comment: Can you please explain the logic of the for loops? Thanks

Comment: @Wiseface I've added some explanation.